# App para ventas en linea

Tags: android

Tengo un proyecto nuevo.. una app en android para ventas en linea..

Pero estoy en blanco de como poder hacer para que el usuario pueda pagar con su tarjeta de banco..

Orientenme por favor, que necesito investigar!

Existe alguna librería o algo por el estilo?

necesito hacer algún contrato con el banco?

Comment: Te recomiendo primeramente realizar un analisis de los métodos disponibles, el más común es Google Wallet pero existen más https://www.yeeply.com/blog/metodos-de-pago-m-commerce-y-en-apps-moviles/ .

Comment: Existe una multitud de servicios y formas con sus propios apis con el tema de pagos, En todo caso el contexto de SOes sería para preguntas sobre el uso de una api en particular, o posiblemente diferencias entre dos apis en concreto, pero no para una discusión sobre servicios de pago en general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la necesidad de tu aplicación analiza factores como:

- ¿Son pagos nacionales o internacionales?
- ¿Tienen preferencia sobre algún banco?
- ¿Cual plataforma ofrece los porcentajes más bajos de comisión por transacción?

Existen muchas plataformas de pago en línea que inclusive permiten pagar a través de tiendas de conveniencia(OXXO, 7Eleven, Supermercados, Etc..).

Puedes consultar algunos de estos:

**Internacionales:**

- Paypal
- Stripe

**Nacionales (México)**

- Conekta
- OpenPay
- ComproPago

Espero te de rumbo esta información! PD: Soy nuevo y no puedo dejarte los links de los sitios directamente hasta que adquiera reputación pero puedes googlear :D

Answer (score -1):

Si quieres pagar con Paypal, ésta provee una api para ello (Utilizando android sdk)
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

Si te interesa otras tarjetas nacionales, lo más probable es que debas utilizar una **orientación a servicios** que ellos provean.

Hay métodos más simples, en mi país (Chile), hay una empresa llamada transbank que es la encargada de los movimiento de dinero y https://www.transbank.cl/public/productos-y-servicios/webpay-cl/ y ellos proveen un portal simple para aquellos que no puedan/quieran programar su servicio.

Saludos